# Why POST parameters does not take values?

Tags: jsp

I am new to jsp and I have created first jsp page. 
Here I want to set the user given values to display in the lower text boxes. But after submitting also those takes only null values.
My code looks like below.

```
<form action="index.jsp" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Country</td>
                    <td><input id="countryText" type="text" > </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>City</td>
                    <td><input id="cityText" type="text" ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Check in Date</td>
                    <td><input id="checkinText" type="text" ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>No of Nights</td>
                    <td><input id="noOfNightsText" type="text" ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>No of Rooms</td>
                    <td><input id="noOfRoomsText" value="1" type="text" disabled></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td align="right"><button id="searchButton" type="submit" class="buttonClass">Search Hotels</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Country</td>
                <td><input id="countryTextOutput" value="<%= request.getParameter("countryText")%>" type="text" disabled> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>City</td>
                <td><input id="cityTextOutput" value="<%= request.getParameter("cityText")%>" type="text" disabled></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Check in Date</td>
                <td><input id="checkinTextOutput" value="<%= request.getParameter("checkinText")%>" type="text" disabled></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>No of Nights</td>
                <td><input id="noOfNightsTextOutput" value="<%= request.getParameter("noOfNightsText")%>" type="text" disabled></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>No of Rooms</td>
                <td><input id="noOfRoomsTextOutput" value="<%= request.getParameter("noOfRoomsText")%>" type="text" disabled></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

My Web Interface
[image: Web Interface]

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Also, try adding a name attribute to your inputs.

Comment: @mit: that should be an answer (if you elaborated a bit more).

Answer (score 2):

You need to add name attributes to your input fields, for example:

```
<input id="countryText" type="text" >
```

Should become:

```
<input id="countryText" name="countryText" type="text" >
```

Also make sure your fields are inside the form.

Answer (score 0):

**request.getParameter** takes the name attribute of input element. Here you have given id.
Try adding name attribute to your input elements.

```
<table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Country</td>
                    <td><input name="countryText" type="text" > </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>City</td>
                    <td><input name="cityText" type="text" ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Check in Date</td>
                    <td><input name="checkinText" type="text" ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>No of Nights</td>
                    <td><input name="noOfNightsText" type="text" ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>No of Rooms</td>
                    <td><input name="noOfRoomsText" value="1" type="text" disabled></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td align="right"><button id="searchButton" type="submit" class="buttonClass">Search Hotels</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`request.getParameter` expects name not id to get the value of the field.

so use name attribute and pass that name inside your `request.getParameter(name)`

this will solve your problem 100%

for a quick solution

put your id and name as same. no need to change anything in display

Comment: Hi @KB, both answered at same time ha ha...!! :)